Миграция данных и аннотации @CreateDate и @LastModifiedDate в Spring
При миграции данных из mongoDb в Postgres на полях с этими аннотациями перезаписываются значения дат - на дату миграции. Можно ли программно отключать на время миграции эти аннотации или сделать их приоритет меньше, чтобы значения не перезаписывались. Простое отключение аннотации на время миграции не вариант - нужно всё сделать в 1 MR.
